# SwiftUI onDelete button overlapping my list row

Tags: swift, swiftui

I created my custom list rows and implemented `onDelete` function. The issue is the button is overlapping the height of the list row vertically, like it's not a part of the row I wish the button was. With this overlap it leaves the background black behind the rows as well. I have no issue if I just use the stock list setup, but only becomes an issue when I try to separate the list rows so they are not cluttered together.

But looking at it now, it doesn't appear that my lis rows are truly separated?

Here is a screenshot of the standard list:
[screen1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whiXE.png)

And here is a screenshot of the separated list rows with the button issue:
[screen2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BnFoA.png)

Here is my code:

```
var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                List {
                    if viewModel.isLoading || !searchablePosts.filter({ !$0.isReposted }).isEmpty {
                        Section(header: Text("Pending")) {
                            if viewModel.isLoading {
                                LoadingPlaceholderView()
                                    .onAppear {
                                        ClipboardManager.shared.clearClipboard()
                                    }
                            }
                            ForEach(filteredPosts.filter { !$0.isReposted }) { post in
                                HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0) {
                                    PostView(post: post)
                                        .onTapGesture {
                                            Utilities.triggerHapticFeedback()
                                            self.selectedPost = post
                                            self.isSheetPresented = true
                                            viewModel.markPostAsSelected(post) // This will change isSelected state
                                        }
                                }
                            }
                            .onDelete { offsets in
                                deletePost(at: offsets, from: .pending)
                            }
                        }
                        
                    }
                    
                    if !searchablePosts.filter({ $0.isReposted }).isEmpty {
                        Section(header: Text("Shared")) {
                            ForEach(searchablePosts.filter { $0.isReposted }) { post in
                                PostView(post: post)
                                    .onTapGesture {
                                        Utilities.triggerHapticFeedback()
                                        self.selectedPost = post
                                        self.isSheetPresented = true
                                    }
                                    
                            }
                            .onDelete { offsets in
                                deletePost(at: offsets, from: .reposted)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    
                    if !viewModel.isLoading && searchablePosts.isEmpty {
                        EmptyContentView()
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                    }
                }
                //.searchable(text: $searchText, placement: .navigationBarDrawer(displayMode: .automatic))
                .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
                .listRowBackground(Color.clear) // Remove background
                //.listRowSeparator(.hidden)
                //.listRowBackground(ThemeManager.ListRows(for: colorScheme))
                .background(ThemeManager.backgroundColor(for: colorScheme))
                //.scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
                
                .sheet(isPresented: $isSheetPresented) {
                    MediaPreviewSheet(post: $selectedPost, viewModel: viewModel)
                        .presentationBackground(.ultraThinMaterial)
                        .presentationDragIndicator(.visible)
                        .presentationCornerRadius(20)
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Test2", displayMode: .inline)
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    Menu {
                        Button(action: { selectedFilter = .all }) {
                            Label("Show All", systemImage: "line.3.horizontal")
                        }
                        
                    } label: {
                        Image(systemName: "ellipsis.circle")
                            .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                    }
                }
            }
            
            .confirmationDialog("Are you sure you want to delete all content?", isPresented: $isShowingConfirmationDialog, titleVisibility: .visible) {
                Button("Delete", role: .destructive) {
                    viewModel.deleteAllPosts()
                }
                Button("Cancel", role: .cancel) {}
            }
            
            .onAppear {
                viewModel.checkClipboardAndUpdateContent()
                NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
                    forName: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification,
                    object: nil,
                    queue: .main
                ) { [weak viewModel] _ in
                    viewModel?.checkClipboardAndUpdateContent()
                }
                
            }
            //.onAppear {
            //  viewModel.isLoading = true
            //  }
        }
    }
```

I tried tweaking the button, moving it to different locations to see if I can achieve different behavior.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you can just put `.listRowSpacing(10)` on the list. That's the intended way to "separate the list rows".

Comment: You should be using @State and small View structs not a view model class and large body.

Comment: that was pretty much i needed @Sweeper . thanks you